# how to write a virtual com port to TCP driver?

Tags: c++, serial-port, tcp, driver

Hi I am trying to write a windows virtual com port driver which will divert the data to a IP address. any pointers, best practice will be of help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know of a Open source project called com0com which is virtual com port redirector. there is a subproject called com2tcp in that which you can look at[com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/). otherwise for windows I am not sure you have any open source available
Between there are commercially available software such as the one from Eltima and tactical software. there are few freewares too, you can search by the name comport redirector.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the freewares too:-)

Answer (score 3):

Check out this example of a User Mode Driver from Microsoft:

Archive.org -> Microsoft.com: <s>[Virtual serial driver sample (FakeModem)](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20140824094640/http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Virtual-serial-driver-8383ea42)</s>

Github.com/Microsoft : [Virtual serial driver sample (FakeModem)](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/serial/VirtualSerial)

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the open source project [Null-modem emulator (com0com)](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) which includes a COM port to TCP redirector.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at the software development kit from [Constellation Data Systems, Inc.](http://www.virtualperipherals.com/Virtual-Serial-Port/Virtual-Serial-Port-Sdk-Product-Description.asp)